# How to determine if regex is exact

Tags: regex, string

I'd like to determine if a regex exactly matches against its own contents. My goal is to determine if an arbitrary regex can be replaced by a simple string comparison.

For example, the regex

```
^abc123$
```

exactly matches the string "abc123" and nothing else, so we could replace it with an `input == "abc123"` string comparison.

This regex, on the other hand, matches itself, but also much more

```
^a.*3$
```

matches: "a3", "afoo3", "a.*3". This could **not** be replaced with an `input =="a.*3"` string comparison.

What is the best approach to determining if a regex only matches a single exact string? Is there a complete list of control characters I can look for?

Comment: Rather simple: once you have quantifiers (`+`, `*`, `{n,m}`) or alternatives (character classes: `[aeiou]`) and/or lookarounds (asserting a specific location), string comparisons will not suffice anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most programming languages that support regular expressions should have a helper function for escaping any special regex-characters within a string. Just apply that function to the string and see whether the escaped version is the same as the original (without the `^...$`).

Example in Python:

```
>>> s = "abc123"
>>> re.escape(s) == s
True
>>> s = "a.*3"
>>> re.escape(s) == s
False
```

Comment: Addendum: There might, of course, also be regexes that _do_ use special regex characters and still only match themselves. This might in fact be an interesting variant of regex-golfing, or regex-quining.

Comment: This is brilliant. The only other thing I had to check for was the regex flags. For example, global (`g`) or case-insensitive (`i`) matching.

Comment: In fact, there's another caveat: If the regex contains regex chars that have already been escaped, such as `\\*`, then those chars _might_ get escaped again (at least Python does this; other languages/libraries might handle it differently). So although that regex with escaped (!) special regex chars would only match itself, it would get changed (escaped again) by `re.escape`.